# Windows start /wait /b NOT working

Tags: windows, console, command-line

Despite what [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297%28WS.10%29.aspx) says, I cannot get `start /wait` to work with `/b`, despite stabbing in the dark trying nearly every possible combination of inputs I can imagine. My command path does not contain spaces, so this is ***not*** a quoting issue.

This works:

```
start /wait <path-to-.exe> <param1> <param2> ...
```

This does NOT work:

```
start /wait /b <path-to-.exe> <param1> <param2> ...
```

The program I'm trying to run ***is*** a CLI/console application, so this caveat (from `start /help`) shouldn't apply:

> When executing an application that is a 32-bit GUI application, CMD.EXE does not wait for the application to terminate before returning to the command prompt. This new behavior does NOT occur if executing within a command script.

Comment: Seems to be working in Windows 7. Could you us give the OS Version and application name?

Comment: @jonZ, I can reproduce the problem on a variety of systems, e.g., I've tested Windows 7 SP1 32-bit, 2008 R2 SP1 64-bit, and Windows 2003 SP2 32-bit.  The start command ignores the /wait option if it is followed by /b, e.g., start /wait /b notepad won't wait.  Could you test again?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the implementation of the start command.  There's a simple workaround:

```
start /wait /b mycommand
```

doesn't work (the /wait argument is ignored) but

```
start /b /wait mycommand
```

does.  (Note that in this simple example you might as well just run mycommand directly, but this workaround may be useful if you want use options such as /low or /i.)

Comment: I'm getting the same results here. The waiting I was referring to earlier was the pause after executing `start /wait /b schtasks.exe`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (either way) on Windows 7. I think it depends on what `mycommand` is…

Comment: @martineau, some executables launch a sub-process and then exit.  That case is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Harry: Yes, I am aware of the reason why — I'm looking for a workaround for that scenario (and think one probably exists).

Comment: @martineau, pretty sure I remember at least one question about this somewhere on SE, but I'm having trouble finding it.  I don't think there are any very good solutions from the command line though, you need to write code to do the job properly.

Comment: I just found one with an answer that [looks promising](https://superuser.com/questions/1293730/start-wait-d-not-working) — but it's really a hack.

Comment: @martineau, here's [one of the questions I was thinking of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1683902/886887).  I think I've also seen a klutzy but effective way to do this in batch, by redirecting standard output to a dummy file and then waiting until you can delete the file, which will fail until the process tree has exited.