# start /wait /d - not working

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

**I am trying to create  script that launches a game, waits till it closes, then runs one final command.** Based on my research, I want to use the "/WAIT" flag but it doesn't seem to work :'(. Im on Windows 10 x64 fully updated.

Here is the script:

```
::FreeSoftwareServers

set keymapperdir="G:\JoyToKey\"
set keymapper=JoyToKey.exe
set p1profile="G:\JoyToKey\BLANK.cfg"
set defaultprofile="G:\JoyToKey\Basic.cfg"

start /d %keymapperdir% %keymapper% %p1profile%

start /WAIT /d "G:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\rocketleague\Binaries\Win32" RocketLeague.exe

::pause

start /d %keymapperdir% %keymapper% %defaultprofile%
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish my goal? Or whats not working? I was looking into while loops that look for the exe but that seems overkill and resource wasting. Thanks.

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think the issue is with the fact that RocketLeague is a steam game so the exe calls steam, closes temporarily untill steam opens it, but thats just a guess. This function did work as expected with a non steam game. I wouldn't mind a code review, but I've decided to just do the "while loop" approach to see if the exe is running with a preface of timeout. I have tons of space resources on my home server so its not a huge deal.

Here is how I got it working:

```
::FreeSoftwareServers

set keymapperdir="G:\JoyToKey\"
set keymapper=JoyToKey.exe
set p1profile="G:\JoyToKey\BLANK.cfg"
set defaultprofile="G:\JoyToKey\Basic.cfg"

start /d %keymapperdir% %keymapper% %p1profile%

"G:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\rocketleague\Binaries\Win32\RocketLeague.exe"

TIMEOUT /T 5

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set EXE=RocketLeague.exe
:while1
FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %EXE%"') DO IF %%x == %EXE% goto FOUND
goto FIN
:FOUND
TIMEOUT /T 5
goto :while1
:FIN

start /d %keymapperdir% %keymapper% %defaultprofile%
```

I'm better w/ Bash so if this seems ridiculous and somebody has a better approach let me know and I'd accept an answer.